# Edit element's attribute in cinnamon.css

Tags: css, linux-mint

I am a newbie.

I am trying to edit some Linux Mint theme effect.

I got the Mojave theme from [here](https://www.cinnamon-look.org/p/1275087/). By default, this sub menu is scrollable:

[image]

After mouse hovering:

[image]

So how can I expand it by default? Thank you and sorry for my ignorance.